# Add Javascript globally in Magento 2 backend

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, file

I have a custom extension that has a javascript file which need to run on every page in magento 2 backend to use jquery and ajax function, is there a way to do this action with custom extension?

Answer (score 0):

You wiil have to make `YourVendor/YourModule/view/adminhtml/default.xml` for this and paste following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="YourVendor_YourModule::js/yourcustomjs.js"></script>
    </head>
</page>
```

and paste your js code in `YourVendor/YourModule/view/adminhtml/web/js/yourcustomjs.js`

Do remember to deploy static content and flushing and cleaning  cache

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

and give required permissions

```
chmod 777 -R var pub
```